# haproxy rewrite rule reqirep logs

Tags: rewrite, haproxy

I have bunch of haproxy rewrite rules for a particular backend, is there a way to log the complete URL to the backend in the haproxy logs?

Here is sample from my config file..

reqirep ^([^\ ]*)\ /myservice/api/v6/offers/(.*) \1\ /new/v1/offerdetailpage/offers/\2

For a request 
   http://example.com/myservice/api/v6/offers/1234
in the haproxy log i am able to see JUST the backend name & the actual incoming request URL, i want to be see /new/v1/offerdetailpage/offers/1234 as well in the haproxy logs..is it possible?

Can you please tell me which logging field should i configure to get the proxied request path?